# View highest rep users of a tag

Tags: support

It used to be easy to get a list of the highest rep users of a tag by hovering over the tag.

That functionality seems to have been lost. Is there a way to get it?

Comment: Highest rep or highest score? Because for highest rep it would list Jon Skeet for almost all tags.

Comment: @Floern Yes, I meant rep-from-this-tag. I assume that's what you mean by 'score'.

Comment: I don't think there's anything that visibly refers to it as tag score but the tooltips say "score" if you hover over the numbers, both on the per tag page and on your profile if you look at your tags.

Comment: @Floern highest rep user**S**. I'm sure there is only one Jon Skeet

Comment: Also, John Skeet is never even represented in my favorite tags. He's big, but not omnipresent

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can click on the tag, then click on "Top Users".

[image: Tag page, showing "Top Users" link]

Using [support](/questions/tagged/support) as an example, that'll take you to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/support/topusers.

Comment: Clicking on the tag just sends me to the tag's questions.

Comment: Found it! Thanks. Well hidden (compared to where it was)...

Comment: Yuss, [I'm a top user there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAIvF.png). I might be last, but it's something!

Comment: If you click [Learn more...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/support/info) you can also see a top 5, with a reference to the top users page

Comment: @BhargavRao: Interestingly, when I check the page, I see my name in your place (with even less reputation). Seems like there's a feature about displaying the current user... maybe to get an idea of scale?

Comment: @MatthieuM., that's the joke. The current user is always the last person in the top users list. ;)

Comment: @BhargavRao: I didn't know this was a thing; I only checked the page a few times on tags I was way up there ;)

Comment: @BhargavRao Except when you are actually in the Top N :-)

Comment: @BhargavRao - Wow. That seems like an anti-feature. It actively misleads the user.

Comment: @T.J. While I agree that it isn't intuitive (there should have been something like a thicker line in between the list and the current user), you can easily find out that it's just there for comparison (when you can see that the jump is huge, or perhaps look at another tag's top users). So, IMO, I don't think it actively misleads the user.

Comment: @BhargavRao - I don't see how it does anything else. For instance, when I go to the link in Sam's answer, I don't see any significant difference. It's listing a user on a list of Top Users even when they're not a Top User. That's quite clearly misleading. That said, it's [far from the worst misleading thing SE does](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269073/dont-say-i-marked-something-as-a-duplicate-when-i-didnt).

Comment: Hmm, I guess you're correct, @T.J. Perhaps because I'm used to seeing that myself as the last user in many places, I'm not finding it misleading. I wonder if anyone else has similar thoughts as yours (a small MSE search doesn't lead to any results about it, perhaps we need to create a new meta post?)

Comment: @BhargavRao :-) Perhaps. I just hope [that other problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269073/dont-say-i-marked-something-as-a-duplicate-when-i-didnt) gets fixed a bit more quickly than the un-underlined links did (nine years). Depending on how you want to count, it's either 3+ years or 8+ years so far. It's so frustrating, because so much of what SE does they do well, and they fall down on these little, easy-to-fix things. (Don't get me started on Stack Snippets. :-) )

Comment: For the worst misleading thing stuff, yeah, I agree. That's just completely wrong. Something which I used to dislike when I was actively involved in closing questions as duplicates.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hah, asked 8 years, 1 month ago! I guess it's just legacy code and no one wants to touch it, which is why they're not implementing it. (I can't think of any other reason)